# Can we know who voted on our answer?

Tags: support, voting

Just curious: can we know who voted on our answer in Mathematics Stack Exchange?

Comment: The answer is no (by design).

Comment: Sometimes, you can know who downvoted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this is not possible. See e.g. this post on Meta Stack Exchange: [Is there a way to see who voted on your posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12984/295232)

> No, voting is by design anonymous. Not even ♦ moderators have access to information on individual votes.

Knowing who up- or downvoted your post would likely incite *some* users to up- resp. downvote the voters' posts, which we want to avoid: [Stack Exchange is all about the content, not the users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219565/295232).

Comment: @Shubhangi Stack Exchange staff can see individual votes (but rarely feel the need to do so). Moderators can see vote *patterns*, but not individual votes.